# Copy String of a ListViewItem into a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, calculator, listviewitem

So I'm working on a calculator, basically a copy of the Windows Version, as a training excercise. I have implemented a History of past calculations, and I was asked to transform this history from `TextBox` to `Listview`.
What I want to do is copy one of the past calculations back into the `Calculator` `TextBox` when I click on it, just like in the Windows Calculator.

My ListViewCode:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#616161" Name="history" Background="Transparent" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="RetrievePastCalculation" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

And this is the `RetrievePastCalculation` method, but it doesn't work, nothing happens when I click on a `ListViewItem`. I'm new to WPF by the way.

```
private void RetrievePastCalculation(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    innerTextBox.Text = history.SelectedItems.ToString();
}
```

This is where I add items to the `ListView` I think, it's the Equal button method:

```
private void ButtonEquals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Calculator calculate = new Calculator();
    textBox.Text = calculate.Calculate(innerTextBox.Text);

    history.Items.Add(innerTextBox.Text + "=" + textBox.Text);

    innerTextBox.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history.SelectedItems` is a [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so calling `ToString` on it won't give you anything other than the name of the type. If you try it in the debugger (which you should), you'll see that it returns `System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection`. Now, at this point you can either fix your issue one of two ways: you can continue to use your current event-based approach, or you can use binding.

**Events**

With events, you can hook a handler to the `Selected` event for each `ListItem` that you add to the list:

```
private void ButtonEquals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Calculator calculate = new Calculator();
    textBox.Text = calculate.Calculate(innerTextBox.Text);

    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Content = innerTextBox.Text + "=" + textBox.Text;
    item.Selected += HistoryItem_Selected //hooks the handler to the 'Selected' event
    history.Items.Add(item);

    innerTextBox.Clear();
}
```

then define the handler itself:

```
private void HistoryItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // here 'sender' will be the ListItem which you clicked on
   // but since it's an object we need to cast it first
   ListViewItem listItem = (ListViewItem)sender;

   // now all that's left is getting the text and assigning it to the textbox
   innerTextBox.Text = listItem.Content.ToString();
}
```

**Binding**

Binding is much simpler as far as the amount of code is concerned, but has a steeper learning curve. Here, instead of setting the `TextBox.Text` property directly, we will specify a binding expression. This means that the value will always be the same as that of the bound expression.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="history" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=history, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
            <Button Name="ButtonEquals" Content="equals" Click="ButtonEquals_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've run this in a new WPF project and it works as expected: the text box displays whatever text is in the clicked item from the list.

One thing to note is that both solutions assume that you are assigning strings to the `ListViewItem Content`. As you may know, you can assign other controls or any object to the `Content` property of a UI `Control` (`ListViewItem` inherits from `Control`). That's why the `ListViewItem.Add` method takes an argument of type `object` and is not restricted to one of type `string`. If you assigned anything other than a string in your button click event handler, both of the two cases above would likely break.

Comment: When I try that it says that the object does not contain a definition for 'Text'. When I add .ToString() after SelectedItems[0] nothing happens.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what's in the collection at that point?

Comment: It may also be that you're handling the event too early with `MouseLeftButtonDown` so that the item is not in the `SelectedItems` collection at that point. Try handling the `Click` event instead.

Comment: That actually makes sense, I will try that out right now. The selection happens after the click I assume. Edit: I can't use the Click event in the Event property, why is that? Maybe I need PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown?

Comment: I think you're right, I'll try it with binding, still learning and all. Thanks though!

Comment: @tweedledum11 I've updated my answer based on your edit

Comment: Not sure if you'll still read this, but thanks for that. What I did is, I put the Binding/Path line there in the code of the textbox that's supposed to display past calculations from history, but at SelectedItem.Content it says "Cannot resolver property Content in data context 'object'. And I don't think it recognizes my history.

Comment: @tweedledum11 You're welcome. I think the above code works as posted and answers your original question. Since you now have an issue that is unrelated to this question and which would be difficult to troubleshoot in comments without seeing your code, you're better off selecting an answer and posting a new question with your new code.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the value of the TextBox to the SelectedItem of the ListView.  Here's an example:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel>
  <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#616161" Name="history" Background="Transparent" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,10,10,0">
                <ListViewItem>Calc1</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Calc2</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=history, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: I'll try that right now, haven't used something like that before, thanks.

Comment: Ok, it works with the ListViewItems "Calc1" and "Calc2", but when I add new formulas to the history, they won't be copied to my TextBox.

Comment: How do you populate (and add new items) to your ListView?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, I'm relatively new to programming. The code above is all I have of the ListView, and I thought it was ok because the formulas appeared in the history, so they have to be items of the ListView, or not?

Comment: Nevermind, I think this is where I add them, immediately after getting the solution, I edited into the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#616161" Name="history" BorderThickness="1,1" Height="50" Width="200" SelectionChanged="history_SelectionChanged">
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock> A ListView</TextBlock>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            with several
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            items
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=history,Path=SelectedValue.Content}"
            BorderThickness="1,1" Height="50" Width="200"   />
</Grid>
```

It's better if you do it using XAML code. try to select item 0 and 1 to see the difference and understand how listboxworks.

now replace the text of textbox binding with following:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=history,Path=SelectedValue.Content.Text}"
```

and seee the output for item 0. Hopefully you'll achieve desired output with a lot less effort.

Now that you have explained the whole problem i think you need to implement a converter in the text binding of TextBox. like below text

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=history,Path=SelectedValue.Content.Text,Converter={StaticResource mytextconverter}}"
```

and write down a logic to extract a part of text on the basis of '=' char. It's very easy to write a converter class. to write a converter follow the below link:

[WPF Converter example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)